# Running Vapor from Homestead failds

Tags: laravel, homestead, laravel-vapor

I installed Vapor in a brand new Laravel up. When I try to run 'vapor deploy production' I get this error:

```
Running Command: npm ci && npm run prod && rm -rf node_modules
npm ERR! cipm can only install packages with an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1. Run an install with npm@5 or later to generate it, then try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2019-10-23T21_24_09_128Z-debug.log

In Process.php line 254:

  The command "npm ci && npm run prod && rm -rf node_modules" failed.

  Exit Code: 1(General error)

  Working directory: /home/vagrant/code/sales2/.vapor/build/app

  Output:
  ================


  Error Output:
  ================
  npm ERR! cipm can only install packages with an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVers
  ion >= 1. Run an install with npm@5 or later to generate it, then try again.

  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
  npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2019-10-23T21_24_09_128Z-debug.log
```

I sucessfully installed vapor. Created a new project and left the domain setting at default.

Comment: Did you sign up for a vapor account?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what your host operating system was, but I assume it's windows, when you ran "vagrant up" did you do so as administrator?

That said, this is an issue with npm and not Vapor. I'd running the "npm ci && npm run prod && rm -rf node_modules" command ssh'd into your vagrant console and troubleshoot from there.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have configured the node package manager for this project. From your computer and not the homestead if you are using, run this command

```
<project directory>: npm install
```

This will create the necessary file.